# Date sync between host and guest(s)

Tags: sync, vmware-fusion

I'm using Fusion 3.0.1 on MacOs X 10.6.2 and have a Vista VM as guest.

For specific reasons, I need to change the date on the Vista VM and go back in 2009 (exactly the 5 No. 2009).

Every times, I'm changing the date on the Vista VM, few minutes after the VM date is reset with the host date.

On the Vista VM, I've unset the automatic synchronization thought internet.

I've alreaded looked on the vmx file without any success.

Answer (score 1):

In the VMTools inside the Vista VM disable the "Time synchronization between the virtual machine and the host operating system" option.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the VMWare Tools config in the guest system.